# status message on main form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, c#-4.0

I have multiple forms based application in that I have some entry forms, if in entry form filled and submit button clicked then I want to display submitting status in main form status-strip

I used like this but not working

```
Main status = new Main();
status.workStatusStrip.Text = "Submitted Successfully";
```

sample code preferred..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will help you

```
WindowsFormsApplication1
{
     public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static Label statusMessageLabel;
        public static string StatusText { set { statusMessageLabel.Text = value; } }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            statusMessageLabel = label1;

            // from anywhere ->
            Form1.StatusText = "a message";
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have two options, and what option to choose can't be said from your question.

First:

Let your 'data entry form' derive from some base class that defines delegate for status change and an event for that delegate like this

```
public delegate void StatusChange(string Status);
public event StatusChange OnStatusChange;
```

Now in your main form subscribe to that event for each data entry form created like this

```
SomeDataEntry de = new SomeDataEntry();
de.OnStatusChange += StatusChanger;
de.Show(); //  or whatever
```

in form do

```
if (OnStatusChange!=null) {
    OnStatusChange("status text");
}
```

and in main form do

```
void StatusChanger(string Status)
{
    status.Text=Status;
}
```

Second:

Do something like Chandan suggested, but please don't make the member static, instead have an interface, with one member, derive from it, pass the interface to the data entry form, and call its method to update status text from the data entry form.

Comment: thank you Daniel Mosmonder... now its working fine like all i need